# What is the difference between debug and AppStore iOS builds

Tags: codenameone

I use XCode extensions and always modify parts of the delegate & capabilities. So I always re-sign and rebuild every CN1 build from its sources

This makes me have to:

- (Production) submit from XCode to AppStore
- (Debug) get installer via Diawi

Should I therefore stop using the option "Send iOS AppStore build" when building from NetBeans? Until now I have still chosen this option when (re-signing) and sending to Apple's App Store. But I'm not sure I should. Does it do anything other than add certificates? For example, does "Send iOS AppStore build" produce actual different code? I think I read somewhere that AppStore builds had something done to their splash screens, but I can't find this anywhere

If possible I would prefer to only build debug builds because they take shorter to build

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It picks your debug settings from the settings and uses debug environment for icloud. The reason production builds take longer is that it compiles both ARM32 and 64 binaries which takes nearly double the time.